# How to add url option in custom shopify section

Tags: shopify, shopify-template

I need to add url option in my shopify custom section

I am using below code for this but instead entering url I want dynamic selection of url.

```
{
 "type": "text",
 "id": "button_url",
 "label": "Button url"
},
```

Answer (score 0):

please replace code mentioned below.

```
{
 "type": "text",
 "id": "button_url",
 "label": "Button url"
},
```

to

```
{
 "type": "url",
 "id": "button_url",
 "label": "Button url"
},
```